# Rename the [usergroups] tag to [user-groups]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The convention with tags here is to replace spaces with hyphens: [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7), [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking), [graphics-card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card).

By convention, then, the [usergroups](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usergroups) tag really ought to be [user-groups](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-groups), as user is an adjective describing groups.

I'd create the [user-groups](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user-groups) tag and retag them myself, but the system won't let me:

[image]

Could someone with appropriate privileges please rename [usergroups](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usergroups)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

done

```
updating post history, 11 rows affected
updating posts, 9 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [user-groups] and [usergroups] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```